# p is without a common factor of 100000.Prove that power of p decimal representation ends with numbers group 00001.

Tags: number-theory

p is without a common factor of 100000.Prove that power of p decimal representation ends with numbers group 00001.

Also prove that every natural nubmer n exist natural number k, that k power of p decimal representation ends with n zeros and number 1.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: "without common factor of 100000" - do you mean $p$ is an integer that is odd and not divisible by $5$?

Answer (score 1):

By the pigeon-hole principle, we find $k_1<k_2$ with $p^{k_1}\equiv p^{k_2}\pmod{10^{n+1}}$. As $p$ is coprime to $10$, $pa\equiv pb\pmod{10^{n+1}}$ implies $a\equiv b\pmod{10^{n+1}}$. So here we can ultimately conclude $p^0\equiv p^{k_2-k_1}\pmod{10^{n+1}}$, as desired.